# PHP declaring empty arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to make a two-dimensional array based on the number of lets say car parts that is submitted on a form. Is it possible to declare an array of a certain size and THEN go back and fill it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP arrays are dynamically allocated.  There's no reason to create it ahead of time.  Just start using the indexes as you need them:

```
$myNewVar[0] = 'data';
```

Comment: I disagree. Prefilling an array with empty members can avoid later having to check whether the index you want to access has been defined. I'm currently using a technique to pass an array that applies classes to twitter bootstrap elements so that, in my case, my tab pane of choice is already open when I load the page after a redirect. I could have achieved a similar effect with JS, I know, and that would have been fine. My only point is that there are cases when this kind of code is desirable.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [array_fill()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) for that:

```
$array = array_fill(1, 50, "");   // creates [1]...[50] with "" string
```

Comment: He could but he shouldn't. He's also wants to fill it with empty arrays

Comment: Multidimentional array: array_fill(1, 50, array_fill(1, 50, ""));